# Differential equations with a complex variable

Tags: differential-equations, calculus-and-analysis, complex

Is Mathematica able to handle ordinary differential equations where the *variable* itself is complex? I am looking for solutions of ODE systems of the form
$$\left\{
\begin{align}
i\frac{da_1}{dt} &=E_1a_1(t)+\mu\cos(\omega t)a_2(t)
\\ 
i \frac{da_2}{dt}&=\mu\cos(\omega t)a_1(t)+E_2a_2(t),
\end{align}\right.$$
and I need to use the analytical continuation of the solutions to a contour that consists of a number of straight-line segments on the complex plane. (Why? because of things like [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/131272/is-quantum-tunneling-related-to-imaginary-time/131478#131478).)

My naive try would be

```
NDSolve[{
      I a1'[t] == E1 a1[t] + μ Cos[ω t] a2[t], 
      I a2'[t] == E2 a2[t] + μ Cos[ω t] a1[t], 
      a1[0] == 1, a2[0] == 0},
    {a1, a2}, {t, 0, I (2 π)/ω}];
```

<sup>(suitable parameters are $E_1=-1$, $E_2=-1/2$, $\mu=0.1$, $\omega=0.05$)</sup>

but this simply causes an error

```
NDSolve::ndnl: "Endpoint 0. +125.664\ I in {t,0.,0. +125.664\ I} is not a real number"
```

I have looked online but I haven't found any good resources. Is this functionality natively available in Mathematica? Are there easily available add-ons that provide it? Or will I need to manually convert the ODEs into a chain of equations of a real variable?

Comment: You may need to just change the variable t to s=t/I so that it is a real parameter. I think the adjusted equations, with imaginary parts, should not pose a problem for NDSolve. That is to say, coefficients can be complex (I think).

Comment: @DanielLichtblau That is possible, though the path is more complicated (i.e. a number of segments at different angles, and not normally at 90°). I was hoping for the kind of iterator notation used in [`NIntegrate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html), e.g. `NIntegrate[f,{x,x0,x1,…,xk}]`.

Comment: Well, you can also change the variable to $s = t/z_0$ for any fixed complex $z_0$ and still have a real independent variable $s$ to use... would that help? It's still a linear change of variables, you could automate the change of variables in Mathematica (probably even with $z_0$ left unspecified), and that would probably get `NDSolve` working. It would have to be straight lines though (you say "a number of line segments..")?